# How to remember macOS keyboard key symbol?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

A Mac user often encounters the keyboard signs for various keys:

- ⌘（Command）
- ⌥（Option/Alt
- ⇧（Shift)
- ⇪（Caps Lock)
- ⌃（Control)
- ↩（Return)
- ⌅（Enter)

What are these symbols based on? Is there an easy way to memorise them?

Comment: ⌘（Command）= this is most distinct or like a signature of mac,

⌥（Option/Alt = See the line turn into different option, its it picking an option

⇧（Shift) = symbol looks like to lift a bit

⇪（Caps Lock) = lift and lock

⌃（Control) = symbol poiting upward its promoting something to be in command or to have control

↩（Return) = Okay Next

⌅（Enter) = Wait I don't know about this no clue